# `withSession` from `Network.Wreq` and memory usage

Tags: haskell, networking, memory

I'm using `Network.Wreq` for benchmarking and works fine but I would to reduce memory usage per session simulation (if it's possible).

My minimal example compare only spawning process (and perform some trivial IO) with spawning creating `withSession` context (on this context my simulated users perform requests to my site) doing nothing with that sessions.

The relevant code could be

```
let doNothing n _ = let job = randomDelay (1000000, 5000000) >> print n >> job in job
    spawnProcs 0 = hPutStrLn stderr "done"
    spawnProcs n = do   forkOS
                        $ S.withSession     -- **** UNIQUE RELEVANT (I think) DIFFERENCE ****
                        $ doNothing n
                        spawnProcs (n - 1)
```

(complete minimal example at the end)

Empirically, each `withSession` take about 2 Mbytes, the exact heap usage is

[image]

and my workflow

```
$ ghc -O3 -threaded -rtsopts -fforce-recomp minimal.hs 2>&1 | more
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( minimal.hs, minimal.o )
Linking minimal ...
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%M Kbytes" ./minimal 800 0 +RTS -hT -N4 | wc -c
done
42640 Kbytes
29535
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%M Kbytes" ./minimal 400 1 +RTS -hT -N4 | wc -c
done
988016 Kbytes
15879
```

Any suggestion is welcome! :)

Thank you!

(Complete code)

```
import Network.Wreq
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Concurrent
import qualified Network.Wreq.Session as S
import System.Random

randomDelay :: (Int, Int) -> IO ()
randomDelay i = randomRIO i >>= threadDelay

onlySpawn n = do
    let doNothing n = let job = randomDelay (1000000, 5000000) >> print n >> job in job
        spawnProcs 0 = hPutStrLn stderr "done"
        spawnProcs n = do   forkOS $ doNothing n
                            spawnProcs (n - 1)
    spawnProcs n

withSessionSpawn n = do
    let doNothing n _ = let job = randomDelay (1000000, 5000000) >> print n >> job in job
        spawnProcs 0 = hPutStrLn stderr "done"
        spawnProcs n = do   forkOS
                            $ S.withSession     -- **** UNIQUE RELEVANT (I think) DIFFERENCE ****
                            $ doNothing n
                            spawnProcs (n - 1)
    spawnProcs n

main = do
    (n:t:_) <- (map read) <$> getArgs
    case t of
        0 -> onlySpawn n
        1 -> withSessionSpawn n
    threadDelay 30000000 -- 30 seconds and exit
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but why are you using `forkOS`? I can't see any reason to use it in this code. (It probably doesn't do what you think.)

Comment: @Carl no matter (same results) but, from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Concurrent.html "if you want to interact with a foreign library" and I unknown what foreign library use `werq` (or `http.conduit`...)

Comment: `wreq` isn't a foreign library. `forkOS` is useful *only* when interacting with native libraries via the FFI that depend on thread-local state. Other than that, it just adds overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think the problem is how `Network.HTTP.Client` must be used.

In the `module Network.Wreq.Session` file

```
withSession :: (Session -> IO a) -> IO a
withSession = withSessionWith defaultManagerSettings

withSessionWith :: HTTP.ManagerSettings -> (Session -> IO a) -> IO a
withSessionWith settings act = do
  mv <- newMVar $ HTTP.createCookieJar []
  HTTP.withManager settings $ \mgr ->
    act Session { seshCookies = mv
                , seshManager = mgr
                , seshRun = runWith
                }
```

then, one `Manager` is created for each simulation (I think is not possible to share `Manager`).

From `Network.HTTP.Client`: *"Creating a new Manager is a relatively expensive operation, you are advised to share a single Manager between requests instead"*

My solution is add a new function to `module Network.Wreq.Session` file to be able to share `Manager`

```
withSessionWithMgr :: HTTP.Manager -> (Session -> IO a) -> IO a
withSessionWithMgr mgr act = do
  mv <- newMVar $ HTTP.createCookieJar []
  act Session { seshCookies = mv
              , seshManager = mgr
              , seshRun = runWith
              }
```

Now, we can add other test function

```
withSessionSpawnWithMgr n mgr = do
    let doNothing n _ = let job = randomDelay (1000000, 5000000) >> print n >> job in job
        spawnProcs 0 = hPutStrLn stderr "done"
        spawnProcs n = do   forkOS $ withSessionWithMgr mgr $ doNothing n
                            spawnProcs (n - 1)
    spawnProcs n

main = do
    (n:t:_) <- (map read) <$> getArgs
    case t of
        0 -> onlySpawn n
        1 -> withSessionSpawn n
        2 -> newManager defaultManagerSettings >>= withSessionSpawnWithMgr n
    threadDelay 30000000 -- 30 seconds and exit
```

and memory usage is minimal

```
$ time -f "%M Kbytes" ./w 800 0 +RTS -hT -N4 | wc -c
done
42496 Kbytes
1748
$ time -f "%M Kbytes" ./w 800 1 +RTS -hT -N4 | wc -c
done
1895616 Kbytes
5888
$ time -f "%M Kbytes" ./w 800 2 +RTS -hT -N4 | wc -c
done
40284 Kbytes
1661
```

(I will suggest to add this function)